# TFS Reporting Service Configured, but unable to see required reports in Team Explorer - Reports window

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Can any one please suggest how do I enable below standard reports in TFS Reports (Scrum):

1) Status on all iteration (Scrum Template)
2) Burndown and Burnrate (Scrum Template)

TFS Reporting service is configured following below guideline and Scrum Template has been imported.
https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/report/admin/add-reports-to-a-team-project

But what I am able to see is only below four reports and not others:

1) Backlog Overview 2) Release Burndown 3) Sprint Burndown 4) Velocity

**How do I get other reports over here that are listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380706.aspx ?** which appears to be standard, out-of-box reports which can be used directly.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very well-documented if you simply looked on MSDN. I found all of this information by following a few links from the URL you initially provided.

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/report/admin/upload-reports

Basically, you use the [Team Foundation Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to upload the reports.

Comment: Hello Daniel, Thanks for the response. I am already able to see reports like :Backlog Overview, Release Burndown, Sprint Burndown, Velocity" while I browse reporting service.    What I am not able to see are the other reports like Status On All Iterations, BurnRate, Unplanned Work etc.   Do you still suggest to follow steps that are mentioned in the link which you have suggested above with (Upload-Reports)?

Comment: Looks like they are part of Agile Template and Not Scrum Template. Can we have them available even if project is created using Scrum Template?

Comment: @RaghavZaveri you can upload custom reports to specify report folder of team project. Go to report server and navigate to corresponding report folder and click Upload to upload a report. You may need to modify reports (other team project process report) before upload.

Comment: @Starain - Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If the reports are created for another Work Item Template than the one you use in your project then, you might not be able to use the report directly. You might however be able to get it to work with a little editing if it is just a matter of some fields that have other names.

Through the Team Explorer -> Reports click the *Go To Site* text link to get to the Reporting Services web page. Here you can click the little triangle for one of the existing reports and choose *Edit in Report Builder* or create a new one by clicking the *Report Builder* link in the toolbar. I have found that it is far easier to edit an existing report to accommodate your needs than starting from scratch. Over time you might get the hang of it and be able to create your own reports from scratch.